# After removing all elements of an array using the splice method, will the value of the array be undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays

My question is the following:
After removing all elements of an array using the splice method, will the value of the array be undefined?

Thank you.

Comment: When you tried this what did you discover?

Comment: I received undefined, however I am not sure if this is true or I am thinking false.

Comment: If you remove the elements and then `console.log(arr)` you should get `[]`. You should add your code to your question as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing all elements from an array, its value is the same array (just without the elements, as it is now empty). You can see that in the code snippet below:

```js
const array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
console.log('before:', array); // ["a", "b", "c"]

array.splice(0, array.length);
console.log('after:', array); // []
```